# Trying to update OpenSSL on my server... GLIBC errors

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum

So, this started because I'm trying to update OpenSSL on my Amazon EC2 server.  However, when I try run `sudo yum update openssl` I get:
 `Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-37.66.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-37.66.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-37.66.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

I've tried both of the suggest commands with no luck:
`sudo yum update openssl --skip-broken
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    1:openssl-1.0.1e-37.66.amzn1.x86_64 from amzn-updates`

`sudo rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` doesn't make a difference

And... if I try:
`sudo yum install glibc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us.amazonaws.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00
810 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do`

What are my other options?

At the same time you can see:
`[taylor@server~]$ /lib/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.12, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-2).
Compiled on a Linux 3.2.5 system on 2013-02-27.
Available extensions:
    The C stubs add-on version 2.1.2.
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
    RT using linux kernel aio
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.`

Comment: Is this a recent instance ? Or pretty old ?

Comment: in simple words, your openssl and glibc is hosed. If it is not too much of efforts, then create a new instance instead.

Comment: @Rico It's a year old or so.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer can you explain how they are hosed?  They both seem to work fine, just not working well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be a couple of things.  Maybe something you installed with the epel repo requires a specific version of glibc and so it is causing you to not be able to install the latest version.  Or maybe you have the repo metadata out of date.  A couple of things to try.

You can clear the repo metadata with:

```
sudo yum clean all
```

and then

```
sudo yum update openssl
```

You can also try to disable the epel repo temporarily with

```
sudo yum --disablerepo epel update openssl
```

If you don't want to update glibc as part of the update you can also just upgrade openssl to the version that is compiled against glibc 2.12 with the following command:

```
sudo yum --releasever=2013.09 update openssl
```